# Convert string to integer inside a where condition [MYSQL]

Tags: mysql, type-conversion

I would like convert a string parameter in a integer inside a where condition.

Case:

```
SELECT * FROM `pro` WHERE `fld_custom_1` <= '85';
```

I would like convert the `'85'(STRING)` in `85(INTEGER)`.

It's possible?

Comment: MySQL usually does such things automatically; heck, it will even usually convert `'85absdaojfiwefmwef'` to `85`.

Comment: See also: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html CAST() and CONVERT()

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM pro WHERE fld_custom_1 <= cast(@param as unsigned)
```

When `fld_custom_1` is of a number data type then MySQL will **automatically** convert the string parameter to a number to make the comparision.

Comment: Good point, in my comment I had assumed the OP was comparing to an int field; likely an incorrect assumption if they are having problems.

Comment: Yeah, it's a varchar(255) type. Unfortunately i can't remove the ' ' and i must work inside them.. Somethings like '(85)INT'

Comment: Like in my answer: `cast('85' as unsigned)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i must work inside the ' ' and i can't add nothing before or after them,

Comment: Ah, you mean you can't change the query? Then you are out of luck.